# Move messages from one outbound queue to another outbound queue

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

We had a configuration issue with one of our apps that was sending a bunch of messages (about 12k+) to the wrong IP. Since that machine doesn't actually exist they're just sitting in the outbound queue. Is there anyway to move all of those messages to the correct outbound queue?

Answer (score -1):

Use queue explorer to "save" all messages to disk. The "load" them into the destination queue